# "should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found" error is thrown when click on an embedded svg shape

Tags: android, cordova, onclick, tap

I got this error when I tap on an embedded svg shape. I load this html file from an Activity that extends DroidGap. In the html file, I embedded the svg and set an onclick event to one shape in the svg. My problem is, in emulator when I click on that shape, it worked fine, but when I switched to real device it throws me this error `should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found`. Can anyone help?

Comment: "Saw some people got this error in webview, but I load this html file from an Activity that extends DroidGap" -- `DroidGap` uses `WebView`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, modified my question.

Comment: This appears to be the same as what is described here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42518#c12

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your class that extends WebView:

```
@Override

 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        int temp_ScrollY = getScrollY();
        scrollTo(getScrollX(), getScrollY() + 1);
        scrollTo(getScrollX(), temp_ScrollY);

    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following touch listener callback in the webview implementation fixes the issue for me.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    onScrollChanged(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), getScrollX(), getScrollY());
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```